# Table for an Appointment App

Tags: database-design, table, erd

experts,

I am building out an appointment scheduler application. I am seeking advice on how best to tackle this issue.

I am building out my ERD and I am the point where I will be creating a appointment_slots config table. In this table, I need to have a list of all my site locations (their IDs), a reference to the service name/id, and the part I am a bit confused on is how to setup the time intervals for each service during a given start and end times for appointments.

For example, all my stores will have 6 services and each service will have n amount of slots available to book in a given half hour period.

Would the design of the table look as follows?

-storeid
-serviceid
-halfhr1
-halfhr2
-nth half hour (where half hour is a representation of 7am - 5PM.)

Let me know your thoughts and I appreciate your wisdom and help in advance.

Thanks!